# How to enable rendering router-view in aurelia component exported as webcomponents

Tags: javascript, aurelia

What do I need to do to enable `router-view` in webcomponents?

In https://github.com/aurelia/web-components there is statement about `<router-view>`

> Note that calling .useGlobalElements() will remove all global elements
>   from your global resources, including `<router-view>` and `<compose>`

My application is using router-view to implement `tabs` functionality, and works in default SPA rendered application.
Example: my main.js looks like:

```
import { CustomElementRegistry } from 'aurelia-web-components';
import {PLATFORM} from 'aurelia-pal';
import environment from '../environment';

export function configure(aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
      .basicConfiguration()
      .globalResources(PLATFORM.moduleName('components/arraysearchdialog'))
      .globalResources(PLATFORM.moduleName('apps/mycomponent'))
  aurelia.use.developmentLogging(environment.debug ? 'debug' : 'warn');
  if (environment.testing) {
    aurelia.use.plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-testing'));
  }
  aurelia.start().then(() => {
    const registry = aurelia.container.get(CustomElementRegistry);
    registry.useGlobalElements();
  });
}
```

Added the `... new AureliaPlugin({ dist: 'es2015' }), ...` into webpack configuration.

My webcomponent.html using the exported components looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><script type="module" src="app.bundle.js"></script></head>
  <body aurelia-app="webcomponent/main">
  <au-arraysearchdialog></au-arraysearchdialog>
  ...
  <au-mycomponent></au-mycomponent>
  </body>
</html>
```

Both `<au-arraysearchdialog>` and `<au-mycomponent>` are rendered - but without router-view.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you meant with "but without the router-view"?

Comment: @bigopon The components are rendered. Thus webcomponents seems to work. Except what I expect to be shown in place of <router-view>. Thus no tabs and no content of routes are rendered in components.

Comment: It seems that it's enough to add registration of router related plugins into main.js: `aurelia.use.plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-history-browser'))
      .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-templating-resources'))
      .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-templating-router'))`

Comment: cool, you got it working?

Comment: @bigopon yes. It's working now.

Comment: Could you help adding a small post to discourse about what you have related to webcomponent and router? Besides that, you dont need to registwr templating resources manually i feel